# jquery .sortable() on <div>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to let user sort this kind of markup

```
<div id="steps">
   <div class="sort">
       <span></span>
       <textarea/>
   </div>
   <div class="sort">
       <span></span>
       <textarea/>
   </div>
   <div class="sort">
       <span></span>
       <textarea/>
   </div>
   <div class="sort">
       <span></span>
       <textarea/>
   </div>
</div>
```

And i am trying like this:

```
$('.sort').sortable({placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",helper:'clone'}).disableSelection();
```

But i am getting very unexpected behavior, please check:

http://jsfiddle.net/GA4Qs/8/

how can i do it to only let user sort by the step number? (but sort the whole item as a block)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe the following fiddle is what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/GA4Qs/13/

jQuery sortable needs to be applied to the parent element containing the elements you want to be sorted.

```
$('#psP').sortable({placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",helper:'clone'});
```

Also you didn't close your divs in the right place.

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="sortable">
        <span class="stepNum inset">1</span>
        <textarea placeholder="Escribe que hay que hacer en este paso" class="step valid"></textarea>
</div>
```

Not

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="sortable">
        <span class="stepNum inset">1</span>
        <textarea placeholder="Escribe que hay que hacer en este paso" class="step valid"></textarea>
<div style="position: relative;" class="sortable">
```

Answer (score 8):

You're turning .sort into the sortable, when .sortable() should be called on the container of the items you want to sort. What your code does is create 5 separate sortable lists.

Switch to selecting based on the parent container, and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/vRCp8/1/

Answer (score 1):

This one is working fine for me. I changed your selector to use the class name"nubeT"

```
$(function() {

    $('.nubeT').sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        helper: 'clone'
    });

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GA4Qs/11/