# jquery ui - having a sortable area with DIVs and not only UL

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

In all of the examples I found for sortable/droppable code in jQuery UI, the reference is to have an unordered list `<ul>` and list items `<li>` under it.

I want to know how I can do this for `<div>` that are under a certain container (another parent `<div>`). Is this functionality in jQuery UI limited only to lists elements??

Comment: NO you can do for div also

Comment: possible duplicate. See answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9660074/2777098

Comment: You could've tried it before asking this. or atleast a google search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery .sortable() on <div>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659966/jquery-sortable-on-div)

Answer (score -1):

There is a .parent() function in Jquery.

So if you have many divs in each other. Then you use a .parent() on the the child.

So if you have three divs with class="div1","div2","div3" respectively.

and you wrote

$( "div.div3" ).parent().css( "background-color", "red" );

the background color of div with class "div2" would be red. If you call .parent() twice like:

$( "div.div3" ).parent().parent().css( "background-color", "red" );

then the div with class "div1" would have a red background.

There are many ways to go up and down the tree. I would practice traversing found here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Hopefully i was able to help.