# How to make textareas sortable? do i have to put textareas inside lis?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

Here is my jquery:

```
$(".time-block .listgroup").sortable({
    connectWith: $(".time-block .listgroup"),
    items: "> textarea",
    placeholder: "highlight",
    //helper: "clone",
    update: function(event){
    var changeArr= []
    $(this).each(function(){
        changeArr.push({
            text: $(this)
            .children()
            .find("textarea")
            .val()
        })
    })
    // update on localstorage object and save and get on page refresh
    saveEvent()
    }
})
```

Here is what the html looks like:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Timeblocks go here-->
    <div class ="time-block"> 
      <div class ="hour" id="9"> 9 AM</div>
      <ul class= "listgroup"> 
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
      </ul>
      <button class ="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class ="time-block">
      <div class ="hour" id="10"> 10 AM</div>
      <ul class= "listgroup">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea>
      </ul>
      <button class ="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    </div>
```

I believe I put the appropriate CDNs at the bottom of the body:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-touch-punch@0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm a beginner trying to experiment with different functionalities and I don't really understand what is going wrong here. Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what element  you want to sort. Do you want to move Textarea from one time block to another? Or  do you want to move the whole time block?

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) needs to be applied to the parent element that contains the items you want sorted. I think you will get successful results when you create the container in the right place. Application test image, sample codes and references are available below:

[image]

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        helper: 'clone'
    });
})
```

```css
#container {
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.newStep {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: -12px;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    width: 80px !important;
}

.step {
    border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
    font-family: lucida Grande;
    margin: 4px;
}

.stepNumber {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    left: -20px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
}

.inset {
    color: white;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="float:left; clear:both;" id="container">
        <div style="position: relative;" class="sortable">
            <span class="stepNumber inset">1</span>
            <textarea placeholder="1 A.M." name="" id="" cols=100  class="step valid" style="margin-left: 10px;"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div style="position: relative;" class="sortable">
            <span class="stepNumber inset">2</span>
            <textarea placeholder="2 A.M." name="" id="" cols=100  class="step valid" style="margin-left: 10px;"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div style="position: relative;" class="sortable">
            <span class="stepNumber inset">3</span>
            <textarea placeholder="3 A.M." name="" id="" cols=100  class="step valid" style="margin-left: 10px;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

###### References

- <sub>[jQuery Sortable Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659966/jquery-sortable-on-div)</sub>

Comment: so, my container is the time-block div within the larger body container. i don't want to make the time-blocks themselves sortable as much as i want the uls with class listgroup to be. in this case, is there something else wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following based on the Demo: [Sortable | jQuery UI | Include / exclude Items](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items).

```js
$(function() {
  function toArray(sort) {
    var results = [];
    $("li", sort).each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).hasClass("hour")) {
        results.push({
          hour: $(el).attr("id"),
          details: $(el).next().find("textarea").text()
        });
      }
    });
    return results;
  }

  function saveEvent(string) {
    //localStorage.setItem("hours", string);
    console.log("Saving", string);
  }

  $(".time-blocks").sortable({
    cancel: ".hour",
    handle: ".fa-grip-lines-vertical",
    update: function(event) {
      saveEvent(JSON.stringify(toArray(this)));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.time-blocks {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

.time-blocks .ui-widget-header {
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.time-blocks textarea {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Timeblocks go here-->
  <ul class="time-blocks ui-widget">
    <li class="hour" id="9">
      <div class="ui-widget-header">9 AM</div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <i class="fas fa-grip-lines-vertical"></i>
        <textarea rows="5">Details 1</textarea>
        <button class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hour" id="10">
      <div class="ui-widget">
        <div class="ui-widget-header">10 AM</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <i class="fas fa-grip-lines-vertical"></i>
        <textarea rows="5">Details 2</textarea>
        <button class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hour" id="11">
      <div class="ui-widget">
        <div class="ui-widget-header">11 AM</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
      <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <i class="fas fa-grip-lines-vertical"></i>
        <textarea rows="5">Details 3</textarea>
        <button class="saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You have one primary list. Each List Item has either Hours or Details. We exclude (`cancel`) the Hours and only worry about sorting the details into Hours.

Since this does not align well, we need a function that can combine the data. This combines the relative data so that we get an Array of Object where the Hours relate to the Details.

Sortable may not be best for this since I suspect you7 only want 1 textarea  per hour. There is a chance the User may drag one into another.